# Is there a way to connect my android phone over wifi to asterisk pbx so can I make make and receive calls via the mobile from my pbx?

Tags: raspberry-pi, asterisk, pbx, sipdroid

I have set up my raspberry pi with Asterisk and FreePBX. I am now trying to get this to be able to use my android mobile phone to make outgoing calls while the phone is in the range of my wifi.

So a good start would be if the pbx could pick up an incoming call and send it to the voice mail. I.e. record what the caller had to say.

I have read that you can do something similar with chan_dongle but looks like its over bluetooth. Can we not just do this over wifi?

Fairly new to all this so will have undoubtedly missed out vital info so please just ask and I will try and keep an eye on the forum and respond.

Comment: [SO is about software development](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), so this question is an off-topic and most likely should be moved to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) or maybe another SE web site. Someone who knows a better grasp of other SE web sites, please suggest the correct one.

Comment: Whoops, sorry and thanks. Will take a look to see if I can find more appropriate SE website. In the mean time if anyone has a suggestion for a better SE website post it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do termination on android softphone.

When call come you have no access to it, android core developers work hard to limit such access.

Phone call done in hardware, hardware gsm core have closed firmware/drivers and thoose interfaces specialy designed to not allow access.

That was done to prevent spy-like apps/viruses and termination too ;)